# Why do my Cypher queries yield different results?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Why do these two queries yield different results:

```
MATCH (keanu:Person {name:"Keanu Reeves"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(kMovie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(actor:Person),
(actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->()<-[:ACTED_IN]-(actor2)
WHERE NOT (actor2)-[:ACTED_IN]->(kMovie) 
RETURN actor2.name, COUNT(actor2) 
ORDER BY COUNT(actor2) DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

And the second one is:

```
MATCH (keanu:Person {name:"Keanu Reeves"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(kMovie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(actor:Person),
(actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->()<-[:ACTED_IN]-(actor2) 
WHERE NOT (actor2)-[:ACTED_IN]->()<-[:ACTED_IN]-(keanu) 
AND keanu <> actor2
RETURN actor2.name, COUNT(actor2) 
ORDER BY COUNT(actor2) DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

The second one gives me the correct result but I don't know why the first one's result is different?

First result:

```
╒═════════════╤═══════════════╕
│"actor2.name"│"COUNT(actor2)"│
╞═════════════╪═══════════════╡
│"Emil Eifrem"│"6"            │
├─────────────┼───────────────┤
│"Tom Hanks"  │"4"            │
├─────────────┼───────────────┤
│"Stephen Rea"│"3"            │
└─────────────┴───────────────┘
```

Second result:

```
╒═════════════╤═══════════════╕
│"actor2.name"│"COUNT(actor2)"│
╞═════════════╪═══════════════╡
│"Tom Hanks"  │"4"            │
├─────────────┼───────────────┤
│"Stephen Rea"│"3"            │
├─────────────┼───────────────┤
│"Ben Miles"  │"3"            │
└─────────────┴───────────────┘
```

The dataset is the sample movie graph dataset that can be created from example graphs part in Neo4j.

Comment: Please post two results and the original data set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your queries are asking different questions.

The first query is asking:

Find Keanu Reeves, **one specific movie he's acted in**, and a coactor in **that one specific movie**, and with that coacter, find a coactor of THEM (coactor2) where coactor2 never acted in **that one specific movie** we selected earlier.

The second query is asking:

Find Keanu Reeves, **one specific movie he's acted in**, and a coactor in **that one specific movie**, and with that coacter, find a coactor of THEM (coactor2) where coactor2 never coacted with Keanu Reeves in any movie (also, make sure coactor2 is not actually Keanu Reeves).

In the results, "Emil Eifrem" co-acted with Keanu in The Matrix, so Emil would never appear in results in the second query no matter which **one specific movie** is used each row.

The reason Emil appears in the first query results is that, for some rows in the result set, the **one specific movie** you matched on (kMovie) was not The Matrix, but some other movie. In those rows, Emil is a coactor (coactor2) of those coactors for other movies, and did not act in whatever **one specific movie** was matched for that row.

As one concrete example of a row here, **that one specific movie** matched was The Matrix Reloaded, where Hugo Weaving was a coactor. Hugo Weaving coacted with Emil in The Matrix, and Emil never acted in The Matrix Reloaded.

The reason Emil has a count of 6 in the first query is because there are 3 coactors with Keanu (Laurence Fishburne, Hugo Weaving, and Carrie-Anne Moss) on 2 different movies that are not The Matrix (The Matrix Reloaded and The Matrix Revolutions), and all 3 of those coactors coacted with Emil on The Matrix, and Emil never acted in The Matrix Reloaded or The Matrix Revolutions. 3 (coactors) * 2 (movies) = 6 rows emitted where Emil appears in the result set.

I hope that explains the differences between the two queries adequately.

Comment: Thanks great answer

Answer (score 0):

Since you're saying your second query gets you the results that you want, let's break that one down.

`MATCH (keanu:Person {name:"Keanu Reeves"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(kMovie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(actor:Person)` is identifying the Person(s) with the name Keanu Reeves as `keanu` that ACTED_IN something what we call `kMovie`, that at least another Person called `actor` ACTED_IN.

`(actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->()<-[:ACTED_IN]-(actor2) WHERE NOT (actor2)-[:ACTED_IN]->()<-[:ACTED_IN]-(keanu) AND keanu <> actor2` That actor also ACTED_IN something that (another) `actor2` ACTED_IN, which didn't ACTED_IN something together with `keanu` (but isn't keanu himself).

`RETURN actor2.name, COUNT(actor2)` Now you're simply interested in the name of that Person and in how many results (rows) that Person shows up, actually you're only interested in the top 3 results: `ORDER BY COUNT(actor2) DESC LIMIT 3`

On why this yields different results compared to the first query.
`WHERE NOT (actor2)-[:ACTED_IN]->(kMovie)` remember, that `kMovie` is a movie that both `keanu` and `actor` acted in. Which is different to the second query of just asking for movies where `keanu` didn't act in (not caring about `actor`'s participation or not.